# COM object c++/cli

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer, com, c++-cli

I am trying to use the the maged c++/cli assembly as an object within html.

```
<object classid="http://127.0.0.1/xxx/yyy_CLI.dll#FooClass" id="dummy" ></object>
```

The class seems like that

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

[Guid("D81FDD51-ABB0-480b-A5F9-0DE209C8456E")]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public interface class IFooClass
{
    virtual void Initialize() = 0;
};

[Guid("D0556663-B16C-403f-B6E1-C5154BE54EF9")]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public ref class FooClass: public IFooClass
{
public:
    FooClass(void);
    virtual ~FooClass(void);

    virtual void Initialize();

};
```

However when javascript is trying to call the Initialize method it says
"...Error: Object doesn't support this property or method..."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I might be way off here, it's been ages since I touched COM, but here it goes:

I think you need to set the Interface type via the `InterfaceType` attribute. something like:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType::InterfaceIsDual)]
[Guid("D81FDD51-ABB0-480b-A5F9-0DE209C8456E")]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public interface class IFooClass
{
...
}
```

Also, **you need to export the managed classes to COM** with the [Tlbexp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfzzah2c%28VS.80%29.aspx) (Type Library Exporter).